# Random points within a grid cell on a line

Tags: qgis, point, random

[image]I'm trying to create random points on a line within a grid cell. I have a river layer within a state boundary. I have placed a grid over the state boundary. I would like to assign 5 random points along the river line with each grid cell in the state layer.

Comment: Hi Christine, What software are you using?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I’m using QGIS

Answer (score 1):

I think it would help with some more explaining. An illustration may help.

From what you have written, I guess that you could

1. Clip the river using the state polygon (to remove the parts of the river that are outside the state boundary) using the *Clip* algorithm.
2. Use your grid to split the river into parts using the *Intersection* algorithm.
3. Generate points on the lines using the *Random points along line* algorithm. Only problem is that this algorithm does not do what it is supposed to do... See comments below.

### Update

After learning about the behaviour of the *Random points along line* algorithm, I made a new QGIS Processing algorithm (*Random points on lines*) that will create random points on each feature of a line dataset (see PR: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/34631).  It supports multi-geometries, so if your river crosses a grid boundary more than two times, you can still generate the specified number of points distributed over the river parts within that grid cell.

Comment: _Random points along line_ tool doesn't work in that way. See: [Incorrect short help for "Random points along line" algorithm](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33160).

Comment: From the documentation: *This algorithm creates a new point layer, with points placed in the lines of another layer.
For each line in the input layer, a given number of points is added to the resulting layer. A minimum distance can be specified to avoid point being too close to each other.*

Comment: The documentation must be fixed.

Comment: That seems to be the case, yes!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I've tried many methods and am just not getting what I need. I'm sorry if it wasn't clear. I have attached a picture.I need 5 random points on the rivers per grid cell so that each individual grid cell has 5 points within it. I have been able to assign points to the river layer and the state separately but not combining them to get the individual cells.

Comment: I have a pull request (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/34605) that should fix the algorithm help for *Random points along lines* in QGIS.